# fire postback inside updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitefinity

What would be the reason that the postback is not fired inside of an update panel.

The markup looks like: http://pastebin.com/U0y0RFfw (couldn't paste markup here)

jQuery Code, trying to fire the postback with this code:

```
$('.rl-submit-button').on('click', function (e) {

            if ($('select.BrandNameList').selectmenu("index") != 0 && $('select.FuelTypeList').selectmenu("index") != 0 && $('select.LeasingPriceList').selectmenu("index") != 0) {
                __doPostBack($('.rl-submit-button').attr('clientid'), '')
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

In code behind (.cs file) I'm setting the Event Handler like:

```
GSSubmitButton.ServerClick += new EventHandler(submitButton_Click);
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that you don't have validation preventing the postback?

Comment: @JamesJohnson: Not sure what you mean, can you give me details?

Comment: Often times when you don't get any response where a postback should be triggered, there is required field validation somewhere preventing the postback.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console if using firebug or chrome? what happens if you set a breakpoint in the javascript above, does it get called?